# intersection of p

Tags: java, permutation, bit

I want to count the number of bit string that Not consists of two consecutive ones **OR** 3 consecutive zeros

**BUT not both**

I found an algorithms for those which consists of  two consecutive ones **OR** 3 consecutive zeros but I failed in finding the intersection between them as I want to exclude it..

For example, my input is 4. I need to find all the 4 bit length sequences that don't have three consecutive 0s or two consecutive 1s. So the answer would be 5: 0010, 0100, 0101, 1001 and 1010

any Ideas?
Thanks..

Comment: Could you elaborate? What's the algorithm that hasn't worked? What output do you expect for what input?

Comment: For example, my input is 4. I need to find all the 4 bit length sequences that don't have three consecutive 0s or two consecutive 1s. So the answer would be 5: 0010, 0100, 0101, 1001 and 1010

Comment: Did you forget a »*not*« in your question? Your example is the opposite of what was described in your first sentence. Also please edit your answer instead of putting the examples and additional requirements into comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach:

- Compute the number of sequences recursively.
- To know the number of subsequences, we need to know the two bits before the subsequence.
- If the previous bit is `1...` then the subsequence has to start with a `0`.
- If the two previous bits are `00...` then the subsequence has to start with a `1`.
- If the previous bits do not match any of these patterns, the subsequence may start with `0` or `1`.

The rest should be clear from the program:

```
public class BitSequences {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 64; ++i) {
            System.out.println(i + " " + bitSequences(i));
        }
    }

    public static long bitSequences(int length) {
        return bitSequences(length, Bit.NONE, Bit.NONE);
    }

    public static long bitSequences(int length, Bit prePreBit, Bit preBit) {
        if (length <= 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (preBit == Bit.ONE) {
            return bitSequences(length - 1, preBit, Bit.ZERO);
        } else if (prePreBit == Bit.ZERO && prePreBit == Bit.ZERO) {
            return bitSequences(length - 1, preBit, Bit.ONE);
        }
        return bitSequences(length - 1, preBit, Bit.ONE)
             + bitSequences(length - 1, preBit, Bit.ZERO);
    }

    enum Bit {
        ZERO,
        ONE,
        NONE
    }
}
```

The program could be improved by using dynamic programming, but it may not be important in your case. The computation for `length = 64` finishes in one second. Result: There are 109'870'576 (roughly 2<sup>28</sup>) bit strings of length 64 without `11` or `000` in them.